# Macbook storage is blocked even though files uploaded to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, storage

I'm facing a unique problem - or I'm simply misreading Apple's messages. When I go to Apple > About this Mac > Storage, I can see that 26GB of my Macbook storage is being used for iCloud. Screenshot below:

[image]

However, I also have Store in iCloud set up on my Macbook, so the actual file size of my iCloud folder on the Macbook is quite low (only 3.83GB).  Screenshot below:

[image]

So my question: why is 26GB being blocked on my HDD when really only 3.83GB is physically on my HDD (and the rest online on iCloud)? Anything I can do to help fix this?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of macOS? What is your macbook year (Version)?

Comment: Yes, I'm on the latest version of MacOS that allows pushing older docs to iCloud to save space. My model is a MacBook Air 2015.